# Why would data transferred through an extension cable be different

Tags: hdmi, displayport

This is something that has been bothering me especially when dealing with the latest cables made for DisplayPort or HDMI.

I understand that issues can occur with adapters since you might be dealing with analog / digital signal. However I sometimes encounter problems after adding a simple extension cable.

For instance, I have a Mini-DP port that output to a 4K device properly using an adapter. I added a Mini-DP extension cable in-between the 4K adapter and the output source and suddenly only a QHD resolution is possible.

How is this possible? All the pins are present, shouldn't it just work the same as if it the signal was taken from the source?

Attempting to find cables seems impossible with all the misinformation.

In summary, is there anything more going on or are we just dealing with faulty cables / scammers most of the time (By scammer, I assume they would be putting connectors without fully connecting them to preserve costs or falsely advertise their merchandise)

Comment: [Transmission is hard.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern serial links are very complicated designs, and use many sophisticated protocols to adapt to "RF channel properties". They support various data rates and formats. Usually the link starts at minimal supported link speed, and performs "link training" by sending a stream of test packets. The receiver passes them in parallel through bandwidth equalizers (tunable filters), and selects the best filter that produces least errors, and then uses these optimal parameters. These programmable filters do equalization of attenuation of the channel, and restore signals to good extent.

Then, typically, the link requests "capabilities" of link partner. If the partner says it can support higher speeds, the link switches into higher gear. Then it starts link training again at this new speed. If the training at higher speed fails, the link will fall back to known good speed. At least this is what happens in USB 3.2 between Gear_1 and Gear_2 speeds.

So this is why you have bad screen resolutions if you add a bad quality or long cable into the channel.

Comment: This explains everything. I assumed the cables were only linking both connectors using smaller cables, but they are actually transforming it through each cable or adapter.

Comment: Very high-speed cables are limited to 2 meters at most. At 4 meters cable capacitance makes full speed impossible.

Comment: @Sparky256, at Gigabit speeds there is no "cable capacitance", it is a transmission line with constant characteristic impedance, with some frequency-dependent losses. With good quality low-loss dielectric the line can be quite long. Super-speed transmitters have a boost for edges called "pre-emphasis", and receivers have linear equalizers, all designed to compensate the high-speed losses. Extra-long USB 3.0 active cables use 4-meter-segments of ordinary USB 3.0 cable between active repeaters.

Comment: @AliChen. I get what your saying, after all the cable to our house is 75 feet and must handle 2 GHZ signals with little phase shift. What I am saying is that you cannot just 'extend' any HF cable without a penalty. Self-adapting receivers have their limits.